# Node.js - Decrypt an array of encrypted strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

A few days ago I went to the "Security and login" page of facebook. And I noticed that they store our devices so that we can control what devices are using our facebook accounts.

And I thought "Maybe I can create something like this".

So I created a new Node.js env and started coding.

My idea is, imagine that the user already has some devices on the database, so I decided to encrypt them to be safer.

Then when I make a request to the database to get an array of all the user_devices that are stored it should look like this:

```
const user_devices = [
  "972f2e0f09e944af2a51aae0608af08b",
  "1046f21afeda72b832a06dbcb3c713d5",
  "98905cfb376ceea05026cca6d46a660e"
];
```

Then I want to do a foreach loop to Decrypt all of them so that they look like this:

```
const user_devices = [
      "127.0.0.1",
      "127.0.0.2",
      "127.0.0.3"
    ];
```

And then I can use an if statement to validate if the user device that is currently trying to access user account is already saved in the user_devices array.

If it doesn't, I will get the current user device trying to access the account and I will encrypt it and save it to the user_devices array.

I hope you liked the story and I am doing this to challenge myself .

But I got this error:

```
internal/crypto/cipher.js:164
  const ret = this._handle.final();
```

And I don't know what to do now .

Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/facebook-security-login-clone-s0y71?file=/src/index.js:148-286

Comment: you need to use the same IV for both encryption and decryption. You are generating a new one each time the page is rendered, so you are not able to decrypt anything that was encrypted with the previous ones

Comment: Also, an encrypted string is not an hash. An hash, by definition, can not be decrypted.

Comment: Can you try adding decipher.setAutoPadding(false); after creating decipher (line 15)?

Comment: @gbalduzzi  Oh ok thank you! So in my IV I just have to remove the crypto.randomBytes(16) to a string, right? just like the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same IV when you encrypt and decrypt. At the same time, an IV is useless if it's always the same one. Best practice is:

- Create a new IV everytime you need to encrypt a new string
- Attach the IV to the encrypted string (maybe just concatenate them) and store the result

When you need to decrypt:

- Separate the IV and the encrypted string again
- Decrypt the string using the key and the IV you just separated

Comment: Oh My God, I get it. I will try to do something more simple. And then I will try to generate a diffent iv and store it with  the encrypted string.